# Can we frame passive sentences if the object is infinitive/gerunds?

Tags: passive-voice

What will be the passive version of the sentence:

> I like to run.
> I like running.

Can I use infinitives and gerunds to frame passive sentences?

> To run is liked by me.
> Running is liked by me.

Are these normal sentences?

Comment: They are grammatically valid but quite unnatural. In real life someone would say "Running is something I enjoy" or similar.

Comment: I suggest first that no-one ever would; to do so would reveal that however correct the words were in this or that text book, you could never be more than a struggling foreigner.

Neither 'To run is liked by me' nor 'Running is liked by me' will ever work.

You might think me pedantic to point out that 'Can we frame passive sentences if the object is infinitive/gerunds' should use '… if the objects are infinitives or gerunds' and does that difference work for you?

I think you won't get closer than 'Running is something I like.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To run is liked by me.

As a native speaker, this doesn't sound like standard usage. Generally the use of the passive voice is to distance the subject from the action. For instance, a child might utter "The toy was broken" looking to escape the obvious consequences that come from "I broke the toy". It's not agrammatical to utter "The toy was broken by me" because "The toy was broken by the dog" is perfectly natural as a response to "Who was the toy broken by?", but it's less efficient than "Who broke the toy?". But to use an infinitive in the subject here feels stilted, even historical. I think a usage panel would reject this as standard English. It would be like saying "Here am I" in the sense that native speakers would be perfectly clear on meaning, but might suspect more Shakespearean English were to follow.

> Running is liked by me.

This also feels awkward, but I would accept this as standard because extensions and alterations of it feel natural. "Running is liked by people" seems perfectly natural as does "Running is liked by many people including me." The use of personal pronouns after 'by' feels awkward. I would entertain a conversation such as:

> "Running is liked by a lot of people."
> "Oh yeah? Running is liked by whom exactly?"
> "Running is liked by *me*!"

with the caveat that the speakers involved might be a little more sophisticated in their language use as whom is a little more literate and used among literate speakers. The second and third line in that conversation would  maintain the structure stated in the first sentence, almost as if an occurrence of [anaphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)), that is to refer back to the original statement. Much more natural and informal would be:

> "A lot of people like to run."
> "Oh yeah? Who likes to run?"
> "*I* like to run!"

> Are these normal sentences?

All of what I said adds up to a healthy "no". If you were to write this way, an English teacher would whittle the text to active voice. If you were to talk this way, a native speaker in my area would either think you're not a native speaker or you're being pretentious (poorly). It's perfectly intelligible, but just awkward to the ear.

When it comes to expressing preference with 'like', 'love', and so on, stick to the active voice.

Comment: "The toy was **broken** by me", surely?

Comment: @KateBunting Surely. If you check the edit log, you'll find I fat fingered a half dozen things. ; ) Feel free to correct anything I ever post.

Comment: Whoa. More extensive than I realized. I grew up in a working class family. Thanks! :D

Comment: "*Generally the use of the passive tense is to distance the subject from the action.*" That is one common reason for using a passive construction. But it can also be used to emphasize what would be the object in an active construction, when the subject seems less important, or even is not known. This is particularly true when the agent is specified in a "by" phrase as an indirect object, and so is not hidden.

Comment: @JD one hypercorrection in there: it should still be "I broke the toy"

Comment: "The toy broke" is not passive; it's active. (Also note that passive isn't a "tense".)

Comment: I agree that the infinitive is to be rejected as Standard English. My immediate, gut response when I saw the two sentences was that 1 is wrong and 2 is fine. With a bit of thought, I revised ‘wrong’ to ‘perhaps not completely ungrammatical, but definitely not _right_ either’, whereas my opinion on 2 remained that it’s perfectly fine.

Comment: @JD Agree with the pretentious assessment.  Substitute 'one' for 'me' (and fluff it out a bit) and you can get close to a normal sounding (in that context) sentence:  "Running is an activity that is rather enjoyed by one".  (Insert plums and silver spoons as appropriate for accent accuracy.)

Comment: @psmears Voice, and yes, it was active, duh. Thanks for the catches. I took a beating on this post!

Comment: @mcalex Plums and silver spoons like Charles Winchester the III? :D

Answer (score 5):

Infinitives (such as "to run") and gerunds (such as "running") can, indeed, function as subjects that take passive predicates. However, infinitives do so rarely, and even gerunds do not do so very often. The active-voice versions of your sentences would be much more common and natural.